# trying to understand stdin, stdout

Tags: c, stdout, echo, stdin

I am trying to understand `stdin`, `stdout`...and these are few questions i have
here's the code i am using:

```
int main()  
{  
    struct termios new;  
    tcgetattr(1,&new);  
    new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;  
    tcsetattr(1,TCSAFLUSH,&new);  
    return 0;  
}
```

I want to know what happens if i turn `ECHO` off on `stdin` rather than `stdout`....i mean, in both the cases i experience same result....how do they differ??

And what does `stty` command returns??
After running the above program, i did `stty` and found -echo for line=0, if i am right, it is `ECHO` off on `stdin`, but the program turns the `ECHO` flag off for `stdout`??
Sorry, if my doubts sound noob :(

Comment: Maybe I'm clueless here, but I guess those are more questions on terminal control than on stdin/stdout. The latter are, in my understanding, only simple data streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is terminal control. And if both your stdin and stdout are connected to the same terminal, then you are still managing the same objects configuration.

`tcgetattr` simply gets information about the object associated with the filedescriptor.

Of course they don't have to be associated with the same terminal. For example if you run:

`./a.out >file.out` then stdin will still be attached to the terminal, but stdout is now attached to a file.